# Laravel: how to set checkbox to be checked on default?

Tags: laravel

How to set checkbox to be checked on default but use same form for create and edit ?

I have form :

```
{!! Form::model($product, ['route' => $formRoute, 'method' => $formMethod]) !!}

    {{ Form::checkbox('is_active') }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and I want is_active to be checked on create, but load from $model on edit, if I put :

```
{{ Form::checkbox('is_active', 1, true) }}
```

it is checked on create, but is also checked on edit even if in db is unchecked (false).

I am looking for best solution...

Comment: `(isset($product->is_active) ? $product->is_active : true)` have you tried something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('is_active', 1, isset($product) ? true : false) }}
```

We are assuming that you have a $product var in your edit form

Comment: you need to handle old data too in case of validation failure